# PHP: Output current script name

Tags: php, string, syntax-error

Why the code below:

```php
echo "Usage: " basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php') "<arg2> <arg1>";
```

produces the following syntax error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'basename' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should concatenate with `.` operator to provide the string as 1 argument to `echo`:

```php
echo "Usage: " . basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php') . "<arg2> <arg1>";
```

*or* use `,` to provide as multiple :

```php
echo "Usage: ", basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php'), "<arg2> <arg1>";
```

Comment: What is `, '.php'`. Am I allowed to discard it?

Comment: @MortezaLSC : It is not required, but you can use it to cut off the suffix of the file, for example, if file is `index.php`, then only `index` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo __FILE__; //to get the current filename.
```

So your code becomes:

```php
if($argc!=3){
   echo "Usage: ".__FILE__.".php <arg2> <arg1>";
   die;
}
```

Comment: You might want to look up what the second parameter of the `basename()` function does.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use commas, like this:

```
if ($argc != 3) {
    echo "Usage:", basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]), '.php', "<arg2> <arg1>";
    die;
}
```